# Determine the x value of the infinite radical

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Determine the value of $X$

$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{...}}}}=1$$

Attemp: Let the LHS be $k$. Square both sides, then you get $x+k=1=k\implies x=0$. However, $\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}$ is equal to $0$ because it never can be positive. Thus, no solution.

Comment: How did you get $x+k = 1 = k$?  You seem to be missing a radical...

Comment: What you've done is correct! Assuming $k=1$.

Comment: So $k=1{}{}{}$?

Comment: I'd write $\sqrt{x+1}=1$ and go from there....

Comment: But yes, there are in fact no solutions.

Comment: @Xander substitution of $k$ under the first radical, then squaring.

Comment: This can be done directly by substituting $1$ under the radical, so $\sqrt{x + 1} = 1 \implies x + 1 = 1 \implies x = 0$, and substitution shows that this solution is extraneous, so there is in fact $\boxed{\text{no solution}}$.